# XPATH selections containing some strings but not others

Tags: xpath

I have the following XPATH that selects elements containing certain strings ("video" or "color" or "black and white").  The issue I am having is that one of the elements that is selected contains a string "video reprints" and although it's correct, I do not want this particular element selected.  I thought I could specify NOT in the XPATH as in the following...

`//div/A[contains(., 'video') or contains(., 'color') or contains(., 'black and white') and (not (contains(., 'reprint')))]`

Any thoughts on how I can remove any selection that contains the string "reprints" from the  selections above?

Answer (score 1):

This is a precedence issue. Just wrap all the or-ed conditions into parentheses:

```
[( ... or ... or ...) and (not(...))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Really it's just because of the way you have your parentheses, so this will work:

```
//div/A[(contains(., 'video') or contains(., 'color') or contains(., 'black and white')) and not(contains(., 'reprints'))]
```